# I am getting error while running application.Failed to register URL for site (application)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure, iis, iis-6

error code :***0x800700b7*** 
Can not create file when that file is already exist.

**I am trying to run web application along with wcf service(Multiple start up projects)**

> Please see image below.

[image]

Comment: Try running Visual Studio with administrator priveleges - you'll need that level to register the URL.

Comment: it is already in admin mode

Comment: Take a look at this article here - it has another solution: [Fixing the error “Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server. Failed to register URL. Access is denied.”](http://saintgimp.org/2012/05/03/fixing-the-error-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-failed-to-register-url-access-is-denied/)